# Two Applications using the same index file with Hibernate Search

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-indexing, hibernate-search

I want to know if it is possible to use the same index file for an entity in two applications. Let me be more specific:

We have an online Application with a frondend for the users and an application for the backend tasks (= administrator interface). Both are running on the same JBOSS AS. Both Applications are using the same database, so they are using the same entities. Of course the package names are not the same in both applications for the entities.

So this is our usecase: A user should be able to search via the frondend. The user is only allowed to see results which are tagged with "visible". This tagging happens in our admin interface, so the index for the frontend should be updated every time an entity is tagged as "visible" in the backend.

Of course both applications do have the same index root folder. In my index folder there are 2 index files:

de.x.x.admin.model.Product
de.x.x.frondend.model.Product

How to "merge" this via Hibernate Search Configuration? I just did not get it via the documentation...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems, that this is not possible...

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I have a WebService that consults a table from a database I only have reading permission, and it's too slow. Now, can Hibernate Search help me with that?